# How to keep my text justified with same space between under flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve the words to be shared with same whitespace around. But not getting the solution. any one help me? in my try you can find the unordered space between word(s).

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width:80%;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.parent span{
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <span>one text</span>
 <span>small</span>
 <span>lengthy texter than one</span>
 <span>medium text two</span>
 <span>one</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code like this:

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly; /* important */
  width:80%;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.parent span{
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <span>one text</span>
 <span>small</span>
 <span>lengthy texter than one</span>
 <span>medium text two</span>
 <span>one</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `space-evenly` currently works in Firefox and Chrome, but not Edge. (I didn't test in Safari.)